# MySQL Join multiple SELECT query

Tags: mysql

I tried to join the following SELECT statements using UNION but I ended up getting all the results on the same column.
However, I would like the results of each query to be in a separate column.

```
SELECT Player_id,Game_id, R1
FROM poker_hands f, poker_cards a, poker_cards b
WHERE f.r1 = a.card_name 
AND f.r2 = b.card_name 
AND (f.hand_type = 'Four of kind' 
AND (a.game_value != b.game_value)
UNION ALL
/* R2 */
SELECT Player_id,Game_id, R2
FROM poker_hands f, poker_cards a, poker_cards b
WHERE f.r1 = a.card_name 
AND f.r2 = b.card_name 
AND (f.hand_type = 'High hand'
AND (a.game_value != b.game_value);
```

I want the output something like that

```
Player_id | Game_id | R1 | R2
0001      | 0002    |    | 8S
0002      | 0003    | 9H |
0003      | 0004    | 5C | 5S
0004      | 0005    |    | 6D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `case` `statement`, try like this:

```
SELECT Player_id,Game_id, CASE WHEN f.hand_type = 'Four of kind' THEN R1 ELSE '' END as R1,
CASE WHEN f.hand_type = 'High hand' THEN R2 ELSE '' END AS R2
FROM poker_hands f, poker_cards a, poker_cards b
WHERE f.r1 = a.card_name 
AND f.r2 = b.card_name 
AND (a.game_value != b.game_value AND (f.hand_type = 'High hand' OR f.hand_type = 'Four of kind' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your rest of the query is correct, use it this way. Hardcode `null` for `R2` in first query and hardcode `null` for `R1` is second query.

```
SELECT Player_id,Game_id, R1 , '' as R2
FROM poker_hands f, poker_cards a, poker_cards b
WHERE f.r1 = a.card_name 
AND f.r2 = b.card_name 
AND (f.hand_type = 'Four of kind' 
AND (a.game_value != b.game_value)
UNION ALL
/* R2 */
SELECT Player_id,Game_id, '' as R1, R2
FROM poker_hands f, poker_cards a, poker_cards b
WHERE f.r1 = a.card_name 
AND f.r2 = b.card_name 
AND (f.hand_type = 'High hand'
AND (a.game_value != b.game_value);
```

Comment: It worked, but how can I replace the NULL with empty space?

Comment: Replace "Union All " with "Union" to remove duplicates

Comment: Is there any way that Player_id,Game_id appears only once, 
what i am getting is that
Player_id | Game_id  | R1  | R2
0001        | 0002        |        | 8S
0001        | 0002        |9H   |
0002        | 0003        |9H   |
0002        | 0003        |        |10D